# Centering text inside a fixed 50% centered image

Tags: html, css

I have a large Circle design positioned center of my page, this code works perfectly.

```
#big_center{
position: fixed;
top: 50%;
left: 50%;
margin-top: -287px;
margin-left: -280px;
list-style-type: none;}
```

I want to position CENTERED text inside said circle. I would like to use CSS if possible, but wouldn't mind a JS solution.

Right now I can get the text centered and moving to the page size, but it doesn't seem to move as well as my image does.

```
.nav{
left: 0;
    margin: auto;
    margin-top: -100px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 40%;
    width: 100%;
    list-style-type: none;}

.nav a{
    text-decoration: none;
    font-family:"Century Gothic";
    font-size:50px;
    font-weight:bold;
    line-height:120%;
    color:rgb(255,255,255);
    text-align:center;
    list-style-type: none;}
```

BONUS POINTS if you can remove my bullets... as you can see I have tried and failed.

```
  <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Home</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../css/basic.css">
</head>
<body>
    <div>
        <img src="../img/s_logo.png" id="logo">
    </div>

    <div>
        <img src="../img/b_logo.png" id="big_center">
    </div>

    <div class="nav">
        <ul>
            <li><a href="portrait.html">PORTRAIT</a></li>
            <li><a href="commercial.html">COMMERCIAL</a></li>
            <li><a href="fineart.html">FINE-ART</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>

</body>



</html>
```

Comment: post your html, or make a fidde - jsfiddle.net

Comment: I have now posted the HTML for full viewing.

Comment: Remove bullets: ul {list-style-type: none;}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you put the .nav inside the same div the image is in and set that div to position relative, the text should stay with the image if the image is centered in its containing div.

Comment: OK, I tried this and it's deffinently on the right track. I think you have the right idea, but could you maybe be a bit more clear in your wording, or post an example in code form?

Comment: @newbyJP Right now I'm not where I can readily illustrate with code. If you explain where I was unclear I'll try to explain it more or I'll try to post an example later if you still haven't found a solution.

Comment: Its ok, tweaked it to a point were it was working properly. thanks for the help!